# Filters Terms not working ( ElasticSearch 7 , NEST 7)

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, filtering, nest

I'm using ElarsticSearch 7.7 & NEST 7.7 and I'm trying to filter data by some fields. 
As of 1st try, I need to filter by delivery dates.

it returns documents by the search query.But when I add **deliveryFilter** 
I'm getting 0 documents and it should be 2.

```
  var deliveryFilter = new TermQuery { Name = "Delivery Date Filter", Field = Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.DeliveryDateName), Value = "3-5 days" };
  queryContainer &= deliveryFilter; // it is working without this line
```

It's working fine without this filter. But I need filter by DeliveryDateNames

```
public SearchResult Search(string searchQuery, int storeId, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10, IList<SearchFilter> requestFilter = null, decimal? priceFrom = null, decimal? priceTo = null, string sortBy = null)
        {
          //------ test data----------------------------
        searchQuery = "Nikon";
        priceFrom = 0;
        priceTo = 6550000;
        pageNumber = 1;
        pageSize = 12;
        sortBy = "z-a";   

        var queryContainer = new QueryContainer();

        #region MyRegion

        var multiMatch = new QueryStringQuery
        {
            Fields = Infer.Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.Name)
                     .And(Infer.Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.CategoryName))
                     .And(Infer.Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.AssociatedProducts.Select(x => x.Name))),
            Boost = 1.1,
            Name = "named_query",
            Query = searchQuery,
            DefaultOperator = Operator.Or,
            Analyzer = "standard",
            QuoteAnalyzer = "keyword",
            AllowLeadingWildcard = true,
            MaximumDeterminizedStates = 2,
            Escape = true,
            FuzzyPrefixLength = 2,
            FuzzyMaxExpansions = 3,
            FuzzyRewrite = MultiTermQueryRewrite.ConstantScore,
            Rewrite = MultiTermQueryRewrite.ConstantScore,
            Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
            TieBreaker = 1,
            AnalyzeWildcard = true,
            MinimumShouldMatch = 2,
            QuoteFieldSuffix = "'",
            Lenient = true,
            AutoGenerateSynonymsPhraseQuery = false
        };
        //queryContainer &= multiMatch;

        #endregion

        var deliveryFilter = new TermQuery { Name = "Delivery Date Filter", Field = Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.DeliveryDateName), Value = "3-5 days" };
        queryContainer &= deliveryFilter; // it is working without this line

        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>()
        {
            Profile = true,
            From = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize,
            Size = pageSize,
            Version = true,               
            Query = new BoolQuery
            {
                Must = new QueryContainer[] { multiMatch },
                Filter = new QueryContainer[] { queryContainer }
            }
        };
        var searchResponse = _client.Search<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(searchRequest);
```

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, it sounds like you expect aggregations to filter the hits for a search result? Aggregations don't filter hits to a search but instead collect results in the `"aggs"` on a response, keyed by the aggregation name. If you need to filter search hits, you'd want to form a compound `bool` query with a `filter` clause. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html

Comment: yes.I was wrong about that.And I have followed your link and I added  this term to query **queryContainer &= new TermQuery { Field = Field<ElasticIndexGroupProduct>(p => p.DeliveryDateName), Value = "3-5 days" };** . But it returns 0 documents and result should be 2 documents.

Comment: Also, I have updated my question with the latest code

Comment: I'd recommend writing out the query that you're generating, using `OnRequestCompleted()` or similar: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html. Would need to see sample data and the mapping in the index to ascertain why no results are returned. The majority of the time it's due to using  the wrong data types in the mapping e.g. `text` datatype when `keyword` should be used, etc.

Comment: Solved. I prefer this comment as an answer. You were correct. it was wrong data types in the mapping. When I changed the data type of search attributes to 'keyword' it's working fine. Thank you.